# Is there a way to draw on screen programmatically in android studio using java

Tags: java, android

I want to create an android app that draw on current layout of app without setting any other Contentview. This is the code that I have did but in this code it is creating an other view and then allow to draw but not on current layout.

```
**Canva Class:**

public CanvaClass(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint = new Paint();
    path = new Path();

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float xPosition = event.getX();
    float yPosition = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(xPosition,yPosition);
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(xPosition,yPosition);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;

        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
 }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CanvaClass canvaClass = new CanvaClass(getApplicationContext(),null);
            setContentView(canvaClass);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not on current layout"?

Comment: Why don't you add your view to existing content view, or put it inside your xml to be there from beginning?

Comment: Actually i have a video player app and i need to draw on video screen and then take its screen shot

Comment: Actually i have a video player app and i need to draw on video screen and then take its screen shot